# PHP checking Radio button then outputting Name and Price

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a few radio buttons, A and B. Both have four radio buttons. 
My code now echos the value of the selected radio button, but this is not what I want. I want it to check which button is selected and then echo the name of the product and also the price.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ordering System</title>

<!-- include css file here-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

  </head>   

  <body>

<?php

 //prices of Radio A
  $A1 = 10;
  $A2 = 20;
  $A3 = 30;
  $A4 = 50;  
 //prices of Radio B
  $B1 = 20;
  $B2 = 30;
  $B3 = 40;
  $B4 = 50;
?>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
        <h2>A or B</h2><hr/>
        <form method="post" action="form.php">
         <hr/>

        <!---------Radio Button's starts here------> 
         <label class="heading">A:</label><br/>
          <input type="radio" name="A" value="A1">Name Of Product A1<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="A" value="A2">Name Of Product A2<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="A" value="A3">Name Of Product A3<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="A" value="A4">Name Of Product A4<br/><br/>

         <label class="heading">B:</label><br/>
          <input type="radio" name="B" value="B1">Name Of Product B1<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="B" value="B2">Name Of Product B2<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="B" value="B3">Name Of Product B3<br/>

          <input type="radio" name="B" value="B4">Name Of Product B4<br/><br/>


          <?php 
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                if(isset($_POST['A']))
                {
                 echo "First selection:<b> ".$_POST['A']."</b> <br>" ;
                }
                else{ echo "<span>Please choose.</span>";}
                }

                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                if(isset($_POST['B']))
                {
                 echo "Second Selection:<b> ".$_POST['B']."</b>";
                }
                else{ echo "<span>Please choose.</span>";}
                }   

                    $radio = $_POST['A'];
                    if ($radio == 'A1') {
                    echo $A1}
                    ?>

            <hr/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />

         </form>
        </div>
   </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

of course i googled when i got this problem and i found this. But this gives me a error when i implement it like above

Error:
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\OK\form.php on line 78

```
<?php
    $radio = $_POST['RadioName'];
    if ($radio == 'Value') {
    echo "Print The Price Here"}
?>
```

then i found : but this gives me the error:
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\OK\form.php on line 81

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if ($_POST['RadioName'] == "Value")
    {
        echo ""
    }
    else if ($_POST['RadioName'] == "Value2")
    {
        echo ""
    }
}
?>
```

when implemented like:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if ($_POST['A'] == "A1")
    {
        echo $A1
    }
    else if ($_POST['A'] == "A2")
    {
        echo $A2
    }
}
?>
```

Is there another solution? Or can any of these solutions tweaked so that they will work?

Comment: You are missing the semi-colon after echo $A1 , it should be echo $A1; on line 78

Answer (score 0):

Be Aware of radio option While are in a group own with same name but multi values, and in $_post array only name and value is available

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sub class like `checked` or `selected`, use jquery.